# Why The News Is Not Being Pulled [XML JS Query]

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>News Site</title>
<script>
window.document.onload = function () {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "cdcatalog.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
        console.log(xmlDoc);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br/>" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Can't show it.";
        } 
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a beginner in using Ajax and this is my first project. I checked with the format, even validated it with W3 Validator, and it doesn't seem to work.

Nothing is showing on the page. It's completely blank.

Can anyone point out my mistake please?

Comment: Press F12 and look at the console for errors and to see what happens with the ajax.

Comment: It is `getElementById` not getElement**s**byId

Comment: Reason is shown in your browser console. Do a search of that error for full explanation

Comment: Okay, let me check and note back.

Comment: Okay, I changed the URL to a local file on my PC. ==>
xhttp.open("GET", "cdcatalog.xml", true); However it still doesn't show anything. And no error on Browser Console. @jrook also corrected that.

Comment: You can add a `console.log(xmlDoc);` and see if there is anything.

Comment: And it is showing as detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt and HTTP/1.1 200 OK for GET request. Nothing else.

Comment: @jrook nopes it's not showing anything. Please see the updated HTML file above.

Comment: Also change `innerhtml` to `innerHTML`

Comment: Nopes, didn't even show "Can't show it." Here's the xml file that I am using if it's of any help. http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/cd_catalog.xml ==> it is saved as cdcatalog.xml in the same folder on PC.

Answer (score 0):

The `document` object does not have an `onload` property. Using that style of event handler assignment, you are looking for `window.onload`.