# Yet Another Image Slider JQuery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have trying for some time. And I gave a look at the image slider questions already. But I would really appreciate if I get some specific help here. Please tell me where the following code went wrong.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
function slideMe {
  $('.imgcontainer').animate({"margin-left":"-= 100%"}, 2000, function () {
   if($('.imgcontainer').css("margin-left") == (-300%)) {
     $('.imgcontainer').css("margin-left", "0px");
   }
   slideMe();
  });
}
window.onload = slideMe();
```

And here's the script on HTML page:

```
<div class="fitimage">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
     <img src="img/copywrtng.jpg" class="headerimage" alt="copywriting" />
     <img src="img/copywrtng1.jpg" class="headerimage" alt="copywriting" />
     <img src="img/copywrtng2.jpg" class="headerimage" alt="copywriting" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's what I have on CSS:

```
div.fitimage {
    width:100%;
    height:93vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img.headerimage {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
  /*max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;*/
    height:93vh;
}
```

My logic is that as each image takes up 100% width, as the ".imgcontainer" div slides left with margin-left: -100%, each image should come up one by one from the right, until it reaches the last one when it reverts to the first image again.

It's not working!

Please help.

Comment: I see alot of errors in your code `"-= 100%"` suppose to be `-100%`, `== (-300%)` is supposed to be `== ("-300%")`

Comment: @RichardMauritz your guess in also wrong. `.css("margin-left")` returns a px value, not a %

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You mean to say, if I say that margin-left == -300%, it won't work? It returns a pixel value? So, in that case I have use the images' width? But in the CSS, I have set the width: 100%.

Comment: Yes @RokoC.Buljan is right, log it into the `console` to find out the `px` value. Anyway, i was just pointing out that any character needs to get wrapped between `"` signs.

Comment: @SamC the problem here is that if you overflow a parent the children will stack one **below** the other (not on the left) - at least not without using `white-space: nowrap` but than the img `100%` will actually be greater, say 300% or whatever their parent width is.

Comment: One question, why are the images stacking over one another if the parent has overflow:hidden? Shouldn't they just stay hidden horizontally? white-space doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: @SamC in order to make the images stack horizontally inside an overflow parent you need to set `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent, and make sure the inner elements are *inline-block* with `vertical-align:top`, but I used **flexbox** (`display: flex;`) in my example below for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "main" issue is in this line:

```
$('.imgcontainer').css("margin-left") == (-300 % )
                                       // ^^^^^^^^
```

beside you can only use string format `"-300%"`, `.css("margin-left")` **will give you a px value** which you **cannot** compare with a non-computed `%`.

Another **issue** is that the slides set at 100% - will be the width of their container, which might be actually greater (300% for 3 slides).

**Solution:**

Instead I'd suggest you to use a `c` counter that goes like `0,1,2, 0,1... etc`.
Than calculate the overflow-wrapper **width** and animate   `scrollLeft: width * counter` (instead of `-marginLeft`).

Use `display:flex` on the parent and `min-width:100%;` on the child DIV elements (than place your images inside those DIVs instead!)

```js
$(".imgcontainer").each(function(){ // Now you can have multiple independent sliders!

  var $gal = $(this),
      $slides = $gal.children(), // get the slides
      tot = $slides.length, // number of slides
      c = 0; // the counter we mentioned

  (function anim() { // internal animation callback function
    var w = $gal.width();
    c = ++c % tot;   // increment or loop-back counter to 0 
    $gal.delay(2000).animate({scrollLeft: w*c }, 1000, anim); // anim callback !
  }()); // << START!

});
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;} html,body{height:100%;}


.imgcontainer{
  position:relative;
  height: 93%; /* or whatever you see fit */
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imgcontainer > div {
  min-width: 100%;
  background: none 50% 50% / cover;
  /* Set background-image inline (see HTML) */
  /* Or use inner images like you did */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="imgcontainer">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/500x340/0bf);">
    Slide 1
  </div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/500x340/f0b);">
    Slide 2
  </div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/500x340/b0f);">
    Slide 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One question: as we are using `scrollLeft: w*c`, why doesn't it show scroll-bars?

Comment: @SamC because of CSS `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Just wondering, why would the images stack over one another in overflow:hidden position? Shouldn't they just do so horizontally?

Comment: @SamC https://jsfiddle.net/q8pz4dwy/ << see here, so no. Even if you set `overflow:hidden;` to the DIV they stack one-below the other.

Comment: But see now: https://jsfiddle.net/q8pz4dwy/1/ using `white-space: nowrap` . Now that the images are set horizontally you can finally `overflow:hidden;` the parent

Comment: This is just as a side question. [link](https://codepen.io/schttrj/pen/OmmZmO) Why aren't the slides going up totally? I mean, I am not going to do it bottom to top but just learning what's really going on. Your help is really appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: @SamC in your Pen example you're doing it the wrong way. You should not stack callbacks that way. What if one day you decide to have 5 images. All you need to do should be adding images, not editing the JS code stacking more functions. - and BTW, moving one's image margin you're moving automatically all the other images too! See here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjjBov

Comment: @SamC also, margin 100% is not what you think it is. that `-100%` is not related to the parent height vs. image height. You might be wanting to use `transform: translateY(-100%)` instead.

Comment: Right. It would get really messy with all the callbacks! But didn't get the last comment. Like, moving the image margin automatically moving other images...isn't that the idea?

Comment: Also, `-100% is not related to the parent height vs. image height. ` I might be having problem understanding it. Let's say, parent height = 200px and width = 200px and image height and width the same.

Comment: Now, if the parent is serving as a container and overflow is hidden, if we move the first image's margin-top again and again by 200px, should image2, image3 and image4 come up successively? I mean, if the image1 moves 200px up, and it's height is 200px, it goes out of the context, right?

Comment: @SamC in the case you're moving only img1 by steps of `-200px, -400px, 0px` than yes - you should see all three images. You can try it by your self - should not be a hard demo. But margin-top: -100% will not be that "-200px" you expect.

Comment: Right, got your point. Let me try it out and really many thanks for the code. I will let you know what I come up with.

Comment: @SamC sure I'm really curious what you'll come up with! I'm always glad to see someone create a nice custom slider instead of loading unnecessary huge gallery plugins. - P.S: performance-wise another suggestion is to use CSS3 `transitions` and `transform: translate` instead of animating `scroll` `position` or `margin`

Comment: Found out that it is much easier to do with CSS3 animations, but I am practicing jQuery. So stuck with it. Okay, here's two JSBins. [JSBin1](http://jsbin.com/tihida) and [JSBin2](http://jsbin.com/balomo)...this one is yours (had to save it..it's nice!) The thing is, in the first JSBin, when the whole thing restarts, it shows a little jerk if keep the animation speed slow. How to get rid of that? Also I found out that setInterval can be used but it creates disparity in repainting the window and animation.

Comment: @SamC just a question to you: Did you find this answer helpful? If so it would be nice to see it accepted - it's a useful feature that awards 15 rep points to the person who take the time to answer you - and a quick  indicator for future visitors that this answer was - indeed helpful. - Same goes for the answers you got to your previous questions - like **[this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43562837/383904)** for example.

Comment: Of course, it was helpful. Let me select it. You have been very helpful indeed. And I just added a nice little slideshow to my repertoire. Thanks so much, Roko.